# horner's method of hashing

Tags: hash, hashcode

I know how to get the value of hashing a string by horner's method wich takes a three paramettres `String str , int p (prime) and int` m like this

```
p(str)=( sumOf(str(0)+str(1)*M+....+str(n)*M^n) )%p = hashVal
```

but the problem is how to get the string str by giving just hashVal , p and M
for example if I give you `hashval=7` , `p = 11` and `M = 2` you have to give me a string for example "hello" (not right just a suggestion for understanding)
I mean that I don't know how to do the inverse 
and thanks for your help

Comment: Isn't the point of hashing that the inverse is hard, if not impossible, to find uniquely?

Comment: i konw this but i want to get just one if it's possible

Comment: can you explain to me how to do this and thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a unique input from the hash you describe, since the modulo operation throws information away. If you knew the hashval was 7, M=2 and p=11, as in your example, you wouldn't know whether the sumOf(...) was 7, or 18, or so on.

Even if you did, say you knew it was 5, for an example 2-character string you wouldn't be able to work out whether str(0) was 1 and str(1) was 2, for example, or str(0) was 5 and str(1) was 0.

Hashes are usually hard/impossible to reverse, especially uniquely. The simplest way to solve them is to hash all possible inputs and check their outputs. You'll end up with many inputs with the same hashVal (if p in your example is 3 there are only 3 different hashes).

Comment: you can get more information about what i asked here
https://a2oj.com/p?ID=429
best regards